# Creating default object from empty value

Tags: php, joomla, xampp

Using latest version on XAMPP i faced below warning on my joomla:

```
Warning: Creating default object from empty value in F:\xampp\htdocs\modules\mod_random_image_with_fancy_zoom\tmpl\default.php on line 26
```

usually this was fixed by **explicit** definition of new variables, however this time i could not find what to be changed to fix this warning?

```
$pickoneArray = array();
$pickone = rand(0, count($images)-1);
print_r($pickoneArray);
print_r($images[$pickone]);
$pickoneArray[0]->name = $images[$pickone]->name; //this is line 26
$pickoneArray[0]->folder = $images[$pickone]->folder . "/";
```

and here is the output of print_r:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [name] =&gt; pic001.jpg
    [folder] =&gt; images\images\pic_of_the_day\
)
```

as you can see $pickoneArray has nothing to be displayed.

Comment: Why can't you just turn the first line into `$pickoneArray = array(new StdClass());`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$pickoneArray[0]` is nothing, so `$pickoneArray[0]->name = ...` *creates a default object*.
You should create it explicitly:

```
$pickoneArray[0]       = new stdClass;
$pickoneArray[0]->name = ...
```

But since you're just reassigning object properties to identical properties in another object, this would make a lot more sense:

```
$pickoneArray[0] = $images[$pickone];
```

In fact, this could all be boiled down to:

```
$pickoneArray = array($images[array_rand($images)]);
```

But here I'd question why you need an array at all. Why not simply:

```
$pickone = $images[array_rand($images)];
```